# How can I use Family Sharing for purchased apps?

Tags: family-sharing

My girlfriend has just got an iPhone.  I've created a free apple account for her and added it to a family, with myself as the organiser, thinking that this would mean she could download my purchased apps.  But whenever she tries to download an app that I've purchased from the list of my purchases, she gets this message:

> This redownload is not available for this Apple ID either because it was bought by a different user or the item was refunded or cancelled.

If she tries do download it from the main store, she is prompted for payment info.  In either case, no app is downloaded.

We've tried:

- Apps I've had for years
- An app I downloaded today
- Paid and fee apps
- Everything at https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201088
- Everything at https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201454
- Signing out of iTunes and back in (both of us)
- Disabling and re-enabling purchase sharing
- Enabling automatic downloads of apps

I'm not willing to try:

- Adding a payment method for my girlfriend - with nothing else working, I don't trust them not to charge it
- Erase and restore the phone - too much faff
- Removing and re-adding her to the family - I've read there's a limit on how often you can do this

How can I use Family Sharing for purchased apps?  Does it even work?  It really feels at this point like the feature doesn't work at all and that Family Sharing is just a lie.

Comment: I'm the organiser for mine, so this is a bit of guesswork, as I can't look at a 'member' phone right now - check App Store > Updates > Purchased. There ought to be a list in there of the member names & their 'own' apps. You should be able to download any from anyone's list.

Comment: Did your girlfriend accept the invitation that was sent to her?  Make sure you've followed all [these steps](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201088).  I've had family sharing setup for 2 years and I don't have any problems with it so I know it's not a lie and that it works.

Comment: Just adding to the confirmation that it works. We've been using it for years without any issues whatsoever. I'm the organiser, my wife is listed as a Parent/Guardian, and we have three children. We also use Apple Music. In summary, as long as the app supports family sharing (the overwhelming majority do) then all our purchases are shared with each other (unless we manually *hide* a purchase). Stick with it and you'll sort it out. Worst case scenario is you have to contact Apple directly. All the best! :)

Comment: @Tetsujin yes, that gives us the "redownload" message.

Comment: @fsb We've followed all the steps. I'm willing to believe it works if you set it up 2 years ago. Sadly I'm setting it up now, and it seems like they've broken it.

Comment: 'prompted for payment info'... that's the bit missing from my experience. All family members already had payment info & had previously bought or downloaded free apps. I was reminded when someone just downvoted my 'jog its elbow to get it going' answer & the myriad questions we've had here about not being able to download even free apps without payment info on file.

Answer (score 1):

Contact Apple store support. You’ll want them to verify thing s before you try removing and re-adding after they sort out any issues with your or with her account.

I would add payment for her, it won’t get charged once you re-add her and it will help make her account verified in Apple’s eyesore a different account.